# How to pass variable value in selenium-javascript

Tags: jmeter

In script I used `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new java.io.File('result33.csv'), 'User,Items per page,Pagination / Activity,Time to load(ms)' + newline, 'UTF-8', true)` now I want to pass user value and time to load value dynamically (Actually I calculated those value in my script) so how to pass this value in above function?
and can you please provide how to pass variable(which used in script) and its value in Flexible File Writer

Answer (score 0):

You have `WDS.vars` shorthand which provides read/write access to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance so you can do:

```
var foo = WDS.vars.get('foo')
```

to read the `foo` variable value from [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

or

```
WDS.vars.put('foo', 'bar')
```

to create a JMeter Variable called `foo` with the value of `bar`

In order to be able  to use the variables in the Flexible File Writer you need to declare them via [`sample_variables` property,](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) i.e. add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter Installation)

```
sample_variables=foo
```

and next time you start JMeter you will be able to refer the variable as `variable#0`

if you have 2 variables like:

```
sample_variables=foo,bar
```

the first one will be `variable#0`, the second one will be `variable#1`, etc.

More information: [Using the JMeter Flexible File Writer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)